# In UI-Route, how do I prevent parent state from destroying nested views?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I have a parent state with nested views and nested states. The nested view is a list of IPs, it's an expensive call to the server should only happen on first load. Clicking an IP should update the URL and cause the `traffic.details` state to update but not the list. The url should look like : `/traffic/details?ip=127.0.0.1`

The parent url is `/traffic?ip` and `ip` is available to all the nested states. After doing:

```
$state.transitionTo("traffic.details", { ip: "127.0.0.1"});
```

Two scenarios:

- It will update the URL as intended but destroy and recreate the nested views.
- If I `preventDefault()` in the `$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart')` in the parent state it  doesn't reload the nested views and reloads the `traffic.details` state (the expected behavior) but it won't update the URL.

How can I update a parent state's URL without updating its nested view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't update a parent url without reloading all children. Put a state below the parent but above all the children, set it to abstract, and it's url to just '?ip', then remove that same bit from the parent state's URL.

Comment: I did something similar to what you suggested. I added the `?ip` to all the children routes, left the shared logic in the parent scope and removed any mention of `event.preventDefault()`. I think your version makes it clearer by having `?ip` and share code in the same scope/route.

Comment: The above doesnt work when the user refreshes the page. That's because the parent scope loads before the params are available from the route. I'll have to try the method you mentioned.

Comment: Did you have any luck with my solution?